# SSRS 2008 R2 Parameter filter using mutivalue textbox

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS 2008 R2, is it possible to have a parameter that looks for specific data inside a cell?

For example:

I have expression (Fields!input_criteria.Value) which contains multiple values separated by ;#

```
 ;#Action01;#Action02;#Action03;#Action04;#Action05;#
```

Depending on the row the cell can be populated with different combinations

```
 Row 1 = ;#Action01;#Action04;#Action05;#
 Row 5 = ;#Action01;#Action05;#
 Row 7 = ;#Action03;#
 ...
```

I want to create a Parameter to filter the dataset by looking into  Fields!input_criteria.Value and display the rows with the value selected

```
 Available Values:
      Action01
      Action02
      Action03
      Action04
      Action05

 If I select Action01 from the Parameter drop down the report displays only Rows 1 and 5.  If Action04 is selected only Row 1 is displayed.
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the filter on your dataset

1) Write custom code that will accept two parameters one is your parameter selected value separated by comma. You can join your values using

```
 =Join(Parameters!input_criteria.Value.Value, ",")
```

second is your `input_criteria` field value

2)  The method will split the parameter value and loop through the each value and and then using `InStr` it will determine if the calue is present  in `input_criteria` field. If present then it will return true.

3) In filter set the expression as

```
= Code.Yourfunction(Join(Parameters!input_criteria.Value.Value, ","),Fields!input_criteria.Value)
```

4) In filter Set the operator to `=`

5) In filter Set the `value` to the `True`

That will filter all your records which contains your selected  parameter  values.

You can add the custom code in Report by going into menu bar options,

**Report->Report Properties -> Code**

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Instr() function in your filter.

=InStr(Fields!input_criteria.Value,Parameter!param1.Value)

>

0